Barcode recognition with .NET MAUI
I would like to read a one-dimensional barcode via the .NET MAUI application. I used the "ZXing.Net.Maui" library.
I inserted the component into the page
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;assembly=ZXing.Net.MAUI.Controls"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.CameraPage"
             Title="QR Code reader">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView x:Name="cameraBarcodeReaderView"
            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="200" Margin="20"
            BarcodesDetected="BarcodesDetected" />

and initialized
public CameraPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    cameraBarcodeReaderView.Options = new BarcodeReaderOptions
    {
       Formats = BarcodeFormats.OneDimensional,
       TryInverted = true,
       AutoRotate = true
    };
}

When the barcode is scanned, the following function should be called. When I start the application on Windows and Android, I see the camera image correctly, but the barcode recognition function is never called. What am I doing wrong?
private void BarcodesDetected(object sender, BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
{
    var first = e.Results?.FirstOrDefault();
    if (first != null)
        return;
    
    Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () =>
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Barcode detected", first.Value, "OK");
    });
}


Try setting a specific barcode format

It works in Windows, but not in Android! cameraBarcodeReaderView.Options = new BarcodeReaderOptions { Formats = BarcodeFormat.Code128, AutoRotate = true, Multiple = true };

As Jason suggested
cameraBarcodeReaderView.Options = new BarcodeReaderOptions  
{
    Formats = BarcodeFormat.Code128,
    AutoRotate = true,
    Multiple = true  
};

